# PHP String position handling names with apostrophes

Tags: php, mysql, char, strpos, alphanumeric

If there is a name in a database (ie. O'Reilly) and I create the insert statement to insert this name into a database via a SQL query in a PHP script, it will cause an error because the apostrophe in the name will end the string and cause the query to fail ('O'Reilly'). Is there a way to use strpos() to find these apostrophes and replace them with a dash/space/comma/etc.

I have tried

```
$pos = strpos($value, "'"); 

if($pos!==false)
{
  $value[$pos] = "-"; 
}
```

But this will replace more than what I want in some columns. 
I was hoping for something more like

```
$pos = strpos($value, "char'char"); 

if($pos!==false)
{
  $value[$pos] = "-"; 
}
```

Where the words "char" were replaced with some alphanumeric indicator so that the script knew to only replace the apostrophes in the names. Is there a way to do that in PHP?

This question has nothing to do with SQL injection, I am just trying to handle strings with apostrophes in them.

Comment: use `escape string` or `addslashes()` before storing

Comment: @KamranAdil: -infinite. `addslashes()` is about as useful for sql injection prevention as a piece of wet toilet paper is in drying out an ocean. e.g. UTTERLY USELESS.

Comment: @MarcB I agree with you but question was about apostrophes and I mentioned `escape string` before `addsalshes`.

Comment: This question has nothing to do with SQL injection. I'm just trying to handle last names in a database that have an apostrophe.

Comment: It's possible the ANSWER to the question is the same as the one about SQL injection. But the QUESTION is not a duplicate. Voting to reopen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try [`addslashes`](http://php.net/addslashes) to escape the slashes.

```
$string = addslashes($value);
```

Comment: addslashes is utterly USELESS to prevent sql injection, and would only be even mildly useful for any database which uses backslashes as escape characters.

Comment: This question isn't about SQL injection, it's about handling strings with apostrophes in them. There's a time and place for every discussion: stay within the scope of the question.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to replace something in the string, just use `str_replace()`

```
$str = str_replace($str, "'", '-');
```